# Collection as String kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer deserialize

Tags: kotlin, serialization, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlinx.serialization

I'm using `kotlinx.serialization` in a KMP sdk for response parsing. I've seen that the `properties` module can be used to easily create the query map from a given class (I'm using  interface inheritance to produce cleaner and safer code).

An example of a query class could be:

```kotlin
@Serializable
class MyQuery(
  val latitude: QueryCollection<Float>, // alias to `@Serializable(with = ...) Collection<T>`
  val variables: QueryCollection<Variables>,
)
```

I need to generate a `?latitude=1.0,2.0,-3.0&variables=hello,stack,overflow` string from it.

I got everything, but the `deserialize` method working. It's not crucial to get it implemented, but I wanted to get a better understanding of the library. Unfortunately, I couldn't get the single element decoding step from `String` to `T` working.

Here's the trivial code:

```kotlin
class QueryCollectionSerializer<T>(
    private val dataSerializer: KSerializer<T>
) : KSerializer<Collection<T>> {

    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor =
        PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("QueryCollection<T>", PrimitiveKind.STRING)

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Collection<T> =
        TODO("Deserialization not (yet) implemented")

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Collection<T>) =
        encoder.encodeString(value.joinToString(","))

}

typealias QueryCollection<T> = @Serializable(QueryCollectionSerializer::class) Collection<T>
```

Point 1: Is the (string) primitive kind appropriate for this situation? Should I be using a ListSerializer instead?

Point 2: I tried

- decoding one string at a time thruogh `decoder.decodeString().split(',').map { /* magic String -> T... How? Idk */ }`
- Using `decoder.decodeStructure`. I was only able to type/semantically correct code, but it wasn't decoding any element, since I didn't know how to tell the decoder that it should get a new element after a comma

Am I missing something?

I suspect I could be forced to write a custom "Query" format by mostly copying the Properties one, but it honestly seems a bit too much for a feature that I barely anyone would be using (again, this is mostly a thing I want to understand, not just "solve for the sake of the sdk")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Implementing `deserialize`

I do not believe there is any "legitimate" way to implement `deserialize` given how `serialize` has been implemented. The `dataSerializer` has been completely bypassed due to converting the collection directly into a string. That means nothing actually knows the "structure" of the collection's elements. Even if you can reliably split the string by a delimiter, you have no way of knowing *how* to convert each individual string to `T`, let alone knowing what `T` is in the first place.

#### Descriptor

> Point 1: Is the (string) primitive kind appropriate for this situation? Should I be using a ListSerializer instead?

Since you've implemented `serialize` to encode a `String`, using a `PrimitiveSerialDescriptor` with `PrimitiveKind.STRING` is correct.

---

## Custom Serial Formats

You are effectively trying to force a particular serial format via a `KSerializer`. But the format is not the serializer's responsibility. In general, the "flow" of the `kotlinx.serialization` library looks like:

```
+---------------+   +--------------------------+   +---------+   +---------------+
|               |   |                          |   |         |   |               |
| Kotlin Object |-->|  SerializationStrategy*  |-->| Encoder |-->| Serial Format |
|               |   |                          |   |         |   |               |
+---------------+   +--------------------------+   +---------+   +---------------+

+---------------+   +--------------------------+   +---------+   +---------------+
|               |   |                          |   |         |   |               |
| Kotlin Object |<--| DeserializationStrategy* |<--| Decoder |<--| Serial Format |
|               |   |                          |   |         |   |               |
+---------------+   +--------------------------+   +---------+   +---------------+
     
   * KSerializer extends both SerializationStrategy and DeserializationStrategy
```

| Interface | Purpose |
| --- | --- |
| `SerializationStrategy` | Convert an object into primitives to pass to an `Encoder`. |
| `Encoder` | Format primitives into a serial format. |
| `Decoder` | Parse a serial format into primitives. |
| `DeserializationStrategy` | Convert primitives from a `Decoder` into an object. |
| `KSerializer` | Combination of both the `XXXStrategy` interfaces. Whenever you are creating a custom serializer, you will probably want to implement this interface (necessary if you want to specify your implementation via annotations). |

<sup>**Note:** A serializer can be composed of other serializers. This allows "nested" complex types to be serialized into primitives (e.g., `String`, `Int`, `Boolean`, etc.), and vice versa, without the "parent" serializer actually knowing *how*. For example, the `dataSerializer` in your serializer is what knows how to serialize and deserialize each `T`.</sup>

As you can see, the `Encoder` and `Decoder` are responsible for the serial format. And ideally, a `KSerializer` should be able to work with any implementation of `Encoder` and `Decoder`.

If you want to implement serialization to a certain serial format, and there is no existing library for that format, then you will have to implement your own `Encoder` and/or `Decoder`. The [Kotlin Serialization Guide](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serialization-guide.md) has a section on [creating custom serial formats](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/formats.md#custom-formats-experimental) which may help, if you decide the effort is worth it. Though note custom formats are apparently still experimental.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I now understand much better the kotlinx.serialization library, all thanks to your flow diagram and your interface-purpose table :)